# How To Do Facebook Login in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want use Facebook Login in my React Native app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android 
I used this documents but when run react-native run-android code after complete this steps. I faced

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

this error. Tried `gradlew clean` but it wasn't run

Answer (score 0):

If you want just facebook login this package is what u want https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk, if you are login using firebase this one https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/master/packages/auth.

Also your error is because multidex if your react native project is using android 10 : 
build.gradle

```
 android {
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
      implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // android < 10
      implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' // android 10
    }
```

manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.myapp">
        <application
                android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

MainAplication.java

```
    public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```